# When Exporting the CSV the values become Exponential in Excel, Is there a way we can stop them via C# .Net Code?

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have used the below code, for Exporting a Datatable to CSV, but on download i see the Exponent Values, How can i stop them from my code, as i know this converstion is done by MS-EXCEL,

Is There Any Way i can show the Exact Numbers? 
Code Mentioned Below:

```
      '--------Download In CSV--------------------------------------------

        If dtResult.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.csv")
            Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

            Dim myData As Byte() = csvBytesWriter(dtResult)
            Response.BinaryWrite(myData)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.SuppressContent = True
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

'--------CSV Writer

```
Function csvBytesWriter(ByRef dTable As DataTable) As Byte()

    '--------Columns Name--------------------------------------------

    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim intClmn As Integer = dTable.Columns.Count

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To intClmn - 1 Step i + 1
        sb.Append("""" + dTable.Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString() + """")
        If i = intClmn - 1 Then
            sb.Append(" ")
        Else
            sb.Append(",")
        End If
    Next
    sb.Append(vbNewLine)

    '--------Data By  Columns---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim row As DataRow
    For Each row In dTable.Rows

        Dim ir As Integer = 0
        For ir = 0 To intClmn - 1 Step ir + 1
            sb.Append("""" + row(ir).ToString().Replace("""", """""") + """")
            If ir = intClmn - 1 Then
                sb.Append(" ")
            Else
                sb.Append(",")
            End If

        Next
        sb.Append(vbNewLine)
    Next

    Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString)

End Function
```

Comment: If you want C# code (title) why the VB.NET tag and code? Are you under the impression this is VB's fault?  There are numerous tools and libraries to read and write CSVs without a lot of transforming code.

Comment: I'm also confused as to what this has to do with C#. Does the file get written with exponents or is it just Excel showing the large numbers as exponents?  If the later, then you can change the numeric formatting of the column once its in Excel.  There's no way to make the CSV file tell Excel what format to use though.  For that, you'd have to write it as an xlsx format (don't ask me how to do that - I don't know).

Comment: Please try to add examples what you want to get and what you are getting.

Comment: yes, its VB.net Code, the excel is showing the data in exponent, i have a requirement to download numeric with must not be formatted manually, it should show all numeric characters instead Exponent.

Answer (score 0):

use [Gembox Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet)
it'll get the job done

Comment: Ms. Excel is the need. is this possible via MS. Excel?

Comment: What do u mean excel is the need ? gembox will help you to export the csv file properly.Then do whatever you want with it